# Move to end of line without [END] key in sublime Text2?

Tags: sublimetext2

I have read the key bindings file of Sublime Text 2

```
{ "keys": ["end"], "command": "move_to", "args": {"to": "eol", "extend": false} },
```

I'm wondering if we can move to the end of line without `END` key in keyboard.

In vim, I just `ESC` and `A`, then the cursor would be in the end of line.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

To change the key binding, open `Key Bindings - User` preferences and add a new line between the square brackets. For example, to set the key binding to `Control-Alt-Command-A` you'd use:

```
{ "keys": ["ctrl+alt+super+a"], "command": "move_to", "args": {"to": "eol", "extend": false} }
```

If this line that you're adding is not the last line before the closing square bracket, then you'll need to include a comma at the end of the line. For example:

```
[
{ "keys": ["ctrl+alt+super+a"], "command": "move_to", "args": {"to": "eol", "extend": false} },
{ "keys": ["ctrl+shift+t"], "command": "open_recent_file", "args": {"index" : 0} },
{ "keys": ["super+v"], "command": "paste_and_indent" },
{ "keys": ["super+shift+v"], "command": "paste" }
]
```

You should check the `Key Bindings - Default` preferences to make sure that the key binding you're setting here doesn't conflict with anything else that you might use.

You shouldn't edit the `Key Bindings - Default` preferences directly, because they will be overwritten in Sublime Text 2 upgrades.

Comment: Thanks:) Is that your configure for mac only?

Comment: I'm *pretty* sure it's universal, and that ST2 uses `alt` for both alt & option and `super` for either command or the windows key.

Answer (score 24):

Command+RightArrowKey on Mac.
Control+RightArrowKey on Windows

Comment: Control+RightArrowKey on Windows (and Ubuntu) moves one "word" to the right, not to the end of the line.

Comment: @Aaron at least on OS X, it works. I have no idea about Windows, though.

Comment: Works but it makes me move the hands to the arrow keys, not very efficient.

Answer (score 15):

1) **Hit `Super+Shift+P`** to open *Command Palette* (`Ctrl+Shift+P` on Windows)

2) **Type "kbu"** to open *Preferences: Key Bindings - User*

3) **Copy / paste the following code** into it:

```
[
    { "keys": ["super+;"], "command": "move_to", "args": {"to": "eol", "extend": false} }
]
```

(Note: if the file is not empty then obviously you know what to do.)

4) **Hit `Super+S`** (`Ctrl+S`) to save and you are all set!

I chose `Super+;` shortcut for I often write in PHP and it's convenient to end lines with a semicolon. Other options could be `Ctrl+;` or `Super+.` or whatever else you find convenient.

Comment: For Windows, it's Ctrl + Shift + p (Ctrl, not Super/Win),

Answer (score 3):

like Terminal, Just press `CTRL + e`

Answer (score 2):

If you're a fan of vim you can enable Vintage mode in Sublime Text 2

> Preferences: Settings - User

Then remove Vintage from the ignored_packages.

Answer (score 2):

How about binding something that'll make you faster? This is what I use (from Key bindings - user):

```
[
{ "keys": ["alt+;"], "command": "move_to", "args": {"to": "eol", "extend": false} },
{ "keys": ["alt+shift+;"], "command": "move_to", "args": {"to": "eof", "extend": false} }
]
```

This way, to go to end of the line I use `alt+;`, and to go to eof I use `alt+shift+;`

Or use Vim...

Answer (score 0):

You can just replace the key with something other than "end". Don't edit the main key bindings file though. Add the change to th user version and it will override the defaults.

Answer (score 0):

I use [ESC] and [A] in Sublime too :-) - I know it's a long time after you asked the question, but I've started using VIM recently, and configured Sublime to use [vintage mode](http://www.sublimetext.com/docs/2/vintage.html). As I'm fairly new to Sublime too, I'm not 100% sure, but I think you should edit the user preferences file rather than the default preferences file as suggested in the above link, as I gather the default file can get overwritten, and the user preference will override the default anyway. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes it might not be spelled out in the keyboard's command capabilities, e.g. Fn+right_arrow like on Microsoft's all-in-one keyboard.